# Does the truth value of a material conditional depend on context?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

Suppose the following material conditional "If 1+1=2 then Moon is made of cheese". The antecedent refers to the context of mathematics. In that context "1+1=2" is true. Whereas "Moon is made of cheese" is false. But the truth value of the consequent depends on a different context (real world). So shouldn't we limit our material conditionals only for antecedents and consequents which are part of the same context? Does this contradict the notion of truth tables etc?

Comment: The point of the material conditional is that it depends on truth values only, this is why it does not always match semantic intuitions, but that is by design. *Truth values* may depend on contexts, paradigms or what have you, but that is not *material* conditional's concern. Of course, one can declare some sentences not well formed and/or lacking truth value depending on their context, but then material conditional simply does not apply to them.

Comment: [Relevance Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/) is one attempt to address issues of context, however the conditional statement of relevance logic is not the material conditional of classical logic.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite.

It is correct that "*1 + 1 = 2*" is neither true nor false if you haven't some context in mind. Same thing for "*the Moon is made of green cheese*".

If you write the truth table for "*1 + 1 **≠** 2*" ⊃ "*The Moon is made of green cheese*", the result is as follows:

> **A B C**
>
> **T T T**
>
> **T F F**
>
> **F T T**
>
> **F F T**

KEY

> A = "1 + 1 ≠ 2"
>
> B = "The Moon is made of green cheese"
>
> C = "1 + 1 ≠ 2" ⊃ "The Moon is made of green cheese"

As you can see, the implication is **not valid**, contrary to what most books on mathematical logic would have said only a few years ago on the basis that "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" is usually considered false, and is indeed false in standard arithmetic.

To make it valid, you need to specify the context.

So, for example, you could make the standard assumptions that "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" is false, and that "*The Moon is made of green cheese*" is false.

This still doesn't affect the truth value of the implication "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" ⊃ "*The Moon is made of green cheese*".

However, you can write a new relation:

> "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" is false and "*The Moon is made of green cheese*" is false, therefore, the implication "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" ⊃ "*The Moon is made of green cheese*" is true.

This only because "*1 + 1 ≠ 2*" is here assumed false.

This gives the following truth table:

> **A B C**
>
> **F F T**

And now, the implication is valid ... *according to the definition of the material implication*, which is arbitrary and doesn't provably refer to anything the human mind does.

Comment: Doesn't provably refer to anything the human mind does is very different from arbitrary. Material conditional is selected for desirable technical properties it has and its usefulness in mathematics, for example.  Vector spaces also do not refer to what human mind does, but are not arbitrary.

Comment: @Conifold Fallacious comparison. Vector spaces are concepts conceived to refer to some aspect of the material world. The non-fallacious parallel would be a concept to refer to some aspect of what the human mind does, in this case, the logical implication. This is something the material implication doesn't do. The material implication is arbitrary in the sense that it happens to be only the best approximation to the logical implication mathematicians were able to find in 170 years of mathematical logic. It is essentially an accident in the history of mathematics. Happenstance.

Comment: Vector spaces are used to model all sorts of things, including the human mind, and the use of conditionals is a part of the material world, along with the rest of human behavior, even if human mind were not. Not to mention that uses terms are put to today do not answer to what their predecessors were conceived for anyway. And if historically contingent makes arbitrary then all of mathematics is "arbitrary", so the word would be of little use.

Comment: @Conifold This is also fallacious. You are trying to argue a point using fluffy notions like "arbitrary". I explained in what sense the material implication is arbitrary. You then  implicitly extend my definition and apply this extended definition to mathematics and get an absurd result. Well done but nothing to do with me. If we all did what you just did, we would all be better off shutting our mouths. And the rest of your comment is irrelevant to my last comment and to my answer. Maybe you could try to understand my point?

Comment: I am not arguing a point, only pointing out your mistakes. Take it as you will.

Comment: @Conifold You certainly didn't point out any mistake. You made a comment whose relevance is not apparent save for the fact that you used a few of the words I used.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading (apologies if so), but I don't understand your argument. "As you can see, the implication is not valid"~ What do you mean by 'valid'? Validity is a feature of arguments. It is NOT a feature of statements. Do you mean the statement is not tautologous? Also, your first truth table is confusing. It is merely the standard definition of material implication. It could be true of ANY sentence A or B. If we take either '1 + 1 = 2' or '1 + 1  ≠ 2' as the antecedent, context free as you say, how would one produce the standard definition of material implication but not the other?

Comment: @AngusSt. 1. Yes, tautologous. 2. I explained in my answer why the truth table in this case is what it is. Of course it is the same as that which defines the material implication. However, in this case, it is not the definition, it is the consequence of the application of this definition to the case considered, which happens to be the general case, at least if we don't include the semantic context as assumption.

Comment: @Speakpigeon "To make it valid, you need to specify the context". Do you mean that if we have two axiomatic systems A and B, where in A "P=Every person has 4 balls" and in B "Q=Every person has 3 balls" then "P implies Q" isn't valid (maybe ambiguous?) because the assign of truth value to P or Q depends on what "every person" refers to (either set of persons of A or B).

Comment: @adosar You can say it like this but you are supposed to work with one axiomatic system, not several. You would need first to specify the larger context within which the two first systems are considered, and then it becomes your real axiomatic system. For example, by taking the union of the axioms of the first two systems. And, yes, you would need to make sure that "person" and "ball" mean the same thing in A and in B. Essentially, the set of axioms has to be consistent, which is the real meaning of "system" in "axiomatic system". You cannot have all true axioms if they contradict each other.